# DataGridView CellFormating speed issue?

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell-formatting

I have a DataGridView with a lot of rows around 3k. I need to make some rows in different colors(3 types of colors) depending on specific value. When I do that, there is no problem with 2 types of colors, the problem start if there are 3 colors.
 The scroll bar disappears as it is in 1.img, when I scroll down it appears again. The second problem is when I Double Click on DGV to view details of selected item, the app is not responding. None of the problems appear when there are 2 colors.
This is 1.img
[image: 1.img]

This is the image with 2 colors, as you can see the scroll bar is in its place and when I Double Click, there is no "not responding"
[image: 2.img]
Here is the code with what I am working:

```
private void CheckQuantity(DataGridViewRow dr)
    {
        var art = dr.DataBoundItem as DeArt;
        if (art != null)
            dr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = art.QuantityMin > art.QuantityRemaining ? Color.LightSalmon : Color.Empty;
    }
    private void CheckPVA(DataGridViewRow dr)
    {
        var art = dr.DataBoundItem as DeArt;
        foreach (DeArtPVA v in PVAprice)
        {
            if (dr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.LightSalmon && v.IdArt == art.Id)
            {
                dr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 120, 10);
                break;
            }
            if (v.IdArt == art.Id)
                dr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }

    protected override void DGVWarehouse_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            CheckQuantity(dgrDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
            CheckPVA(dgrDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas why?

Comment: Are you looking at specific Values in one particular column?

Comment: @Derek for one color yes but for other two I am looking in a separate table, with reference on this table.

Answer (score 0):

Would something **ON THE LINES** of this be of use?

```
private void DGVWarehouse_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
            int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;


        if (colIndex == 0 && rowIndex >=0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow theRow = DGVWarehouse.Rows[rowIndex];

            if (theRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() != String.Empty || theRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() != null)
            {

                if (theRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() == "YourArtID")
                {
                    theRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                }
                else if (theRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() == "YourArtID")
                {
                    theRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                }
                else if (theRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() == "YourArtID")
                {
                    theRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                { 
                    // Your DEFAULT STYLE
                }
            }
        }
    }
```